# Facebook API 2.2: Graph error when trying to post a link

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The goal of the script is to post automatically, on my profile and on my groups, the link to a specific page, once the content is created.

But all what I got when I launch the test script here below, is this returned string:

```
Graph returned an error: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

In fact, the token related to the app was given by FB Developers site.
I tried also the combination:

```
634060413388093|9ed702cc524a1cbb59ca1fb7a17839f1
```

But I still get the same return

```
<?php
$path = getcwd();

require_once $path . '/include/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '634060413388093',
    'app_secret' => '9ed702cc524a1cbb59ca1fb7a17839f1',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',  ]);

$linkData = [
  'link' => 'http://www.example.com/page',
  'message' => 'here the new page on my site.',
  ];

try {
    // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
    $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, '634060413388093|bnTyPyRtsZSLHoc1B1w772cz3BU');
    } catch  (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }


$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
echo 'Posted with id: ' . $graphNode['id'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the way in this moment. I tried any example andy help, any suggestion but it didn't work out.
Thus, I post it hoping it helps somebody else with my same issue:

The access token, **is not** app_id|app_secret but it's obtained in another way:
To get the correct access otken, one should go to:

https://developers.facebook.com

under "Tools & Support" select "Graph API Explorer"
On the upper right corner, there is a drop down menu called "Application".
Click and select the created application.
Select "Access Token" shown, and copy/paste it in the field aside `$linkDAta` variable:

`$response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, '{access-token}');`

At that point, launching the script as it is, it worked out :)

**EDIT:**
If you need to post in groups, just change the `'/me/feed'` with '`{group_id}/feed'`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a user access token to read the feed of a user. 'me' refers to the user that is associated with the user access token. An app access token is not associated with any specific user.

This leads to the second point, which is much more important. You should never reveal your app secret, especially not on Stack Overflow or anywhere public. You should hide that part of your SO Question, or better yet, create a new FB application.

Comment: Editing the question won’t help, it will still be visible to users who can see the edit history. Creating a new app however is not necessary – the app secret (and that’s what the second part of the app access token after the pipe symbol is) can be reset in app dashboard. But that should definitively be done now.

Comment: Hi Sleepy Panda: yes I reset the secret code, so that the one here published is not any longer valid.

About the user access token: I'm in the dark, having never used these APIs ...